# OpenCV Using a model to predict if a image belongs to a collection

Tags: python, opencv, training-data

The goal is to compare an image and select what the image contains from a selection of 5 other collections of images. Both the compare image and collection of images the image object takes up 100% of the image size.

I tried using CascadeClassifier to train one collection of images against the others and this solution doesn't really work as intended. Because of my understanding, the CascadeClassifier should be used if the image is much bigger where the object doesn't take up 100% of the size.

**Is there a better way to train a model with the 5 different collections of images to select the most likeness image type? (correct collection)**

Compare image:

[Compare Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0v38.png)

Collections:

[Collection One Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc8tU.png)

[Collection Two Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgQeo.png)

*Keep in mind that each collection consists of hundreds of sample images.*

Comment: just use matchTemplate. when both images are the same size, the "sliding window" will test just one position.

Comment: Is there a way to implement a model with matchTemplate to train the result? Because I had quite bad results with using matchTemplate.

Comment: that *nota bene* needs to go in the *first paragraph*. so you have a **thousand** images, and you have one query image, and you need to know which image in the dataset is most like it. just compare the query to each dataset image with matchTemplate or any other way. -- how you group your dataset is (so far) irrelevant to the task of calculating similarity... because you didn't explain _why_ you group that bunch of pictures into five "collections". so far, there's no evidence that these things share any visual properties that would cause the grouping to help in the task.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.